# How do I link Facebooks comments box to a specific facebook page or application

Tags: facebook

I'm trying to get the facebook comments box to integrate with a microsite that we are developing at work.

We are having some issues getting the comments to show up on either our page or our application that we set up. The comments do however show up on the facebook feed.

Has anyone had any experience setting up the Facebook Comments box to link comments to a page or application. Any resources would be wonderful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to post a comment using the FB pluggins direcly to an Application or a Fan Page. It will only show up on FB livestream for a users account.

Comment: Do you have any citations I can read to confirm this? Quite a bummer really.